# Personal /etc/hosts?

Tags: macos, mac, dns, hosts-file

`/etc/hosts` lets you set system-wide hostname lookups.  Is there a place in OS X to set per-user hostnames?

I use two user accounts on my laptop and I'd like to override IP addresses for just one of those accounts.  Is that possible?

Comment: @Tetsujin this is incorrect. Yosemite or any older versions of OSX, as well as any Linux and FreeBSD distributions that I know of, works with /etc/hosts.

Comment: @Tetsujin first page of your google search result not confirming your claim and contain [question about hosts file](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/158117/os-x-10-10-1-etc-hosts-private-etc-hosts-file-is-being-ignored-and-not-resol)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, DNS is global.

You don't mention any details.

You could redefine:

thissite.com 0.0.0.0

mythissite.com 122.122.122.122  <-- with the IP address of the real site.

Then only people who know that thissite.com is broken and to use mythissinte.com instead would be able to access thissite.com

Comment: As a note this will only work if the site you are masking with a new domain name is listening on that domain, otherwise it may say "nope! I don't know who mythissite.com is!" And return a 404 error

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing in any operating system, but you can swap `/etc/hosts` file by some script when user is logging in.

I don't know much about OS X, you may have to restart one or more network services after that file swap.

You also might want to change permissions or owner on `/etc/hosts` file, if your script will be running from non-administrator account.

Comment: Pretty sure ubuntu has a ~/.hosts